# Как достать нужные символы с помощью matchAll?

Tags: node.js

Есть текстовый файл test2Txt с информацией:

```
id      kladr_full       city_name
76089   770000000000000  Москва
75982   520000010000000  Нижний Новгород
76136   480000010000000  Липецк г.
75225   520000070000000  Выкса г.
75974   520270010000000  Кстово г.
76121   700000010000000  Томск г.
```

Необходимо достать все id, начинающиеcя на 75. Вызов консоли дает `undefined`.Что я делаю не так?

```js
var fs = require("fs");
let fileContent = fs.readFileSync("test2Txt", "utf8");
function findId() {
    var regExp=/75...\s\s\s/g;
    var find=fileContent.matchAll(regExp);
    console.log(find[0])
}
findId();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var content = `id      kladr_full       city_name
76089   770000000000000  Москва
75982   520000010000000  Нижний Новгород
76136   750000010000000  Липецк г.
75225   520000070000000  Выкса г.
75974   520270010000000  Кстово г.
76121   750000010000000  Томск г.`;

console.log(content.match(/^75\d+/gm));
```

Comment: Вот у меня почему-то `^` не срабатывало. Странно. Даже с флагом `/m`. **UPD**: А нет, убрал группирующие `()` и сработало.

Comment: @entithat, по идее скобки не влияют. Может всё-таки флаг забыл? Или там был не match?

Comment: По идее то, что они не влияют это так. Скорее всего дописал `/m` после того, как запустил код для теста xD